# How to add a js file at pub\static\frontend\vendorname\themename\en_US level

Tags: magento2, theme

How to add a js file at `pub\static\frontend\vendorname\themename\en_US`? 
Where should I place the js in my theme in the theme folder at the design directory?
And how can I include the js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a js file in

> app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/web/js/custom.js

```
require(['jquery'],function($) {
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      /* Your code */ 
   });
});
```

Then you need to enqueue that js file in

> app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

Using below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

After creating those files execute **upgrade**, **Content deploy** and **cache** command. And check in pub folder the file will be created.

> pub\static\frontend\vendorname\themename\en_US\js

Comment: just remove /js , the answer is work for me